# Unable to Generate Apex Code from WSDL

Tags: apex, webservices, soap, wsdl, wsdl2apex

I have two salesforce orgs and I am trying to do SOAP integration between these two via WSDL import.

From the first Salesforce Org (let us say S1)

I did the following

a) Clicked on the "WSDL" of my webservice class.

[image]

b) When I clicked on the hyperlink though, it took me to a web page like shown below.

[image]

c) So I saved the webpage as ".wsdl" shown below.

[image]

d) In the second salesforce org (let us say S2) i did the following.

Clicked on "Generate from WSDL"

[image]

e) It asked me to choose the file and here I chose the "AccountAdd.wsdl" file

[image]

f) It gave me a success response for parsing as shown below.

[image]

g) But when I try to generate the apex code it gave me the following error.

[image]

I have also attached the class that I tried for this activity.

```
global class AccountAdd
{

webservice static Account AddingNewAccount(Account a)
{

//custom logic
return null;

}


}
```

This is just a placeholder class without adding actual methods which I will add later.
For now I just wanted to try an import/export of WSDL.

Also I have added the second salesforce org (S2) in the Remote Site Settings on S1 as shown below.

[image]

**Question :**

Can someone please let know as to why I am getting error in S2 (*Step g*)when trying to generated apex code of the AccountAdd.wsdl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue.

I did complete the class and after completing it I tried doing the same (generate/export/import) and now the apex code was successfully generated in the second org.

Answer (score 4):

The native version of Wsdl2Apex doesn't support `{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType` because WebserviceCallout.invoke can't.

By having Account in the methods Arguments and return type Salesforce is going to generate xsd:complexType's for all sorts of supporting types. A number of these will have elements like:

```
<xsd:element name="NewValue" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:anyType" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:element name="OldValue" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:anyType" nillable="true"/>
```

Also, generally speaking, wsdl2apex has great difficulty handling sObject types in a WSDL due to the use of `<xsd:extension base="tns:sObject">`. It won't generate the required base class fields and WebserviceCallout.invoke doesn't support inheritance.

Since it is now working for you I suspect you have altered the definition of the webservice method so that it no longer takes/returns an Account object.

If that isn't the case, you might like to try the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) (Disclosure: The is my current employer). It has an alternative version of Wsdl2Apex that can handle several of these problems. `anyType` is still problematic, but you may no care about the types that actually use it.

If you are really keen, there is also the [open source version of wsdl2apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/09/announcing-open-source-wsdl2apex-generator.html), which you code modify as required.